# Firefox OS App Automation

Tags: html, testing, selenium, automation, firefox-os

I've been searching about Firefox OS/Firefox for Mobile App Automation.

Though there's **Marionette** we can try on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette

I can't seem to find a **Selenium library** to use in testing Firefox OS Apps. Is there any other way we can test web apps on Firefox for Android/Firefox OS?

Comment: What is the problem with Marionette? Does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox OS app testing framework is what is used in general for automated testing on the platform. I will point this out to start with, Marionette is selenium but a customized version optimized for use within Mozilla's Gecko instances.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Firefox_OS/Automated_testing/gaia-ui-tests/Part_2_Marionette_Firefox_OS_interactions

this page will show you how to run interactions inside of firefox os and the guide part3 will show you how to build automated test scripts.
Marionette currently will only work for Firefox os <=2.5 currently as marionette is not working on >2.5.